# Hide contour lines in terrain map type of google static maps API

Tags: google-maps-static-api

I'm using Google static maps API to create terrain textures. Is there a way to hide the contour lines that are shown with some zoom levels? E.g., I need a way to change the following request to hide the contour lines:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=48.412236,15.480091&zoom=15&size=500x300&sensor=false&maptype=terrain&style=feature:water|visibility:off&style=element:labels|visibility:off](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=48.412236,15.480091&zoom=15&size=500x300&sensor=false&maptype=terrain&style=feature:water%7Cvisibility:off&style=element:labels%7Cvisibility:off)

thx,
Jureen

Comment: I thought disabling the `landscape.natural.terrain` feature would hide the contours, but it didn't seem to.  None of the [documented features](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType) looks like a better match :-(